# Change background color of content in ListBoxItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-4.0

I'm a WPF newbie; I have a ListBox that contains expanders (the expanders have a border around them):

```
<ListBox Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightGray" CornerRadius="5">
                <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#f7f7f7">
                    <!-- Content -->
                </Expander>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The behavior I would like is that the selected item have its expander background color become darker (#e0e0e0 for instance).  I found examples that let me hide the background color of the ListBoxItem (this is shown in the code), but no good sources on changing the background color of the content in the ListBoxItem.  I understand that I need to set up a trigger to do this but I don't know how to set it up, whether it be a trigger for the ListBox or the Expander.

How do I set up the appropriate triggers?

Comment: You might want to try Expression Blend that is very good tool to do things like this

Comment: triggers need a condition to evaluate, what condition do you want.  Is the trigger based on a data value or is it simply when that row/item is selected or expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <DataTemplate>
     <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightGray" CornerRadius="5">
       <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#f7f7f7" Name="expander">

       </Expander>
     </Border>
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e0e0e0" TargetName="expander"/>
     </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
 </DataTemplate>
```